# SQL Script can't create some tables

Tags: mysql, database, server

My SQL script firstly says that it is not connected, when i open it, so i connect it by going to Query -> Reconnect to server, which works. Then i try to execute the SQL script which only creates the first two tables are met with an error code 1064, and the errors are at the VISIBLE Index lines. I have no idea what that means as i am completely new to SQL, can anyone help?

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' INDEX userId_idx (userId ASC) VISIBLE, CONSTRAINT gameId FOREIGN ' at line 9

-- MySQL Script generated by MySQL Workbench
    -- Wed Jan  2 02:21:44 2019
    -- Model: New Model    Version: 1.0
    -- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema game_review
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema game_review
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `game_review` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ;
USE `game_review` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `game_review`.`games`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `game_review`.`games` (
  `game_Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `tags` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  `systemReq` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `developer` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `publisher` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `trailer` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `about` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `platform` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `categories` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `description` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `releaseDate` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`game_Id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `game_review`.`users`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `game_review`.`users` (
  `user_Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_Id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `game_review`.`reviews`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `game_review`.`reviews` (
  `review_Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `gameId` INT NOT NULL,
  `userId` INT NOT NULL,
  `review` TEXT(1024) NOT NULL,
  `rating` INT NULL,
  `dateposted` DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`review_Id`),
  INDEX `gameId_idx` (`gameId` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `userId_idx` (`userId` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `gameId`
    FOREIGN KEY (`gameId`)
    REFERENCES `game_review`.`games` (`game_Id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `userId`
    FOREIGN KEY (`userId`)
    REFERENCES `game_review`.`users` (`user_Id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `game_review`.`favourites`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `game_review`.`favourites` (
  `favourites_Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `gameId` INT NOT NULL,
  `userId` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`favourites_Id`),
  INDEX `gameId_idx` (`gameId` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `userId_idx` (`userId` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `gameId`
    FOREIGN KEY (`gameId`)
    REFERENCES `game_review`.`games` (`game_Id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `userId`
    FOREIGN KEY (`userId`)
    REFERENCES `game_review`.`users` (`user_Id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `game_review`.`forum`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `game_review`.`forum` (
  `forum_Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `gameId` INT NOT NULL,
  `userId` INT NOT NULL,
  `topic` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `views` INT NOT NULL,
  `likes` INT NOT NULL,
  `comment` TEXT(300) NULL,
  `totalComments` INT NULL,
  `dateposted` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`forum_Id`),
  INDEX `gameId_idx` (`gameId` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `userId_idx` (`userId` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `gameId`
    FOREIGN KEY (`gameId`)
    REFERENCES `game_review`.`games` (`game_Id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `userId`
    FOREIGN KEY (`userId`)
    REFERENCES `game_review`.`users` (`user_Id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `game_review`.`game cart`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `game_review`.`game cart` (
  `cart_Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `gameId` INT NOT NULL,
  `quantity` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cart_Id`),
  INDEX `gameId_idx` (`gameId` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `gameId`
    FOREIGN KEY (`gameId`)
    REFERENCES `game_review`.`games` (`game_Id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: mysql 1064 is a syntax error. Please post the complete error message that you are getting

Comment: Here is the error code.

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' INDEX userId_idx (userId ASC) VISIBLE, CONSTRAINT gameId FOREIGN ' at line 9

Comment: It didn't work sorry

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration of indexes is not correct : VISIBLE is not recognized syntax. Also, the ASC mention is superfluous as it corrresponds to the default.

Replace :

```
...
INDEX `gameId_idx` (`gameId` ASC) VISIBLE,
INDEX `userId_idx` (`userId` ASC) VISIBLE,
...
```

With :

```
...
INDEX `reviews_gameId_idx` (`gameId`),
INDEX `reviews_userId_idx` (`userId`),
...
```

For more information see [the mysql CREATE INDEX docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html).

Also please bear in mind that, in most RDBMS others than mysql, index names are global across the database schema, hence make sure not to use the same index name twice (I can see that at least index `gameId_idx` is declared twice. One solution is to prefix the index name with the table it belongs to, as shown above.

Foreign key names between different tables also must be unique (you have duplicates like `game_Id`).

Finally I also notice that one of your table name has a space in it (`game cart`) : this is not a good practice, should be avoided.

Comment: The error 1064 went away then i got Error Code: 1005. Can't create table `game_review`.`game cart` (errno: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update")

Comment: What should i do to fix it then? Completely change the name of the indexes (I don't know the impacts of that) or remove the index names? I'm so sorry for all these questions as i literally just started to use SQL. It is weird that these errors still appeared despite the script being forward engineered from Workbench itself.

Comment: @XavierLimJunYi : this one is related to unicorn of foreign keys... answer updated...